# The number of months in a Calendar is not constant?

Tags: java, calendar

From http://www.coderanch.com/t/381676/java/java/number-months-between-two-given, one post mentioned:

```
public static int monthsBetween(Date minuend, Date subtrahend)  
{  
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
// default will be Gregorian in US Locales  
cal.setTime(minuend);  
int minuendMonth =  cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);  
int minuendYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);  
cal.setTime(subtrahend);  
int subtrahendMonth =  cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);  
int subtrahendYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);  

// the following will work okay for Gregorian but will not  
// work correctly in a Calendar where the number of months   
// in a year is not constant  
return ((minuendYear - subtrahendYear) * cal.getMaximum(Calendar.MONTH)) +    
(minuendMonth - subtrahendMonth);  
}
```

Is it true that the number of months in a Calendar is not constant? And why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. In the hebrew calendar, there are several years with 13 months (7 out of 19 to be exact).

Comment: In the above example, does the Calendar.getInstance() return the appropriate locale calendar or does Calendar.getInstance() always return something default, if so what is that default?

Comment: From the docs: `Gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale. The Calendar returned is based on the current time in the default time zone with the default locale.`, I don't use a computer with israel / hebrew locale, only IL timezone, so I can't answer the second question...

Comment: look here for other options: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance()

Answer (score -1):

It is funny that, *month* comes from *moon*. A lunar calendar usually sync days with moon phases, so that, for example, day 15 of any month is always a full moon day.

The problem is a solar year is not exactly 12 moon cycles. So a lunar calendar must have "leap months".